# How to make sub-directories appear in Google Search Engine?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, web-crawlers, robots.txt

I want to know how to effectively SEO manage my personal websites. For example, I have `http://www.janedoe.com/` and in the meta data I have: `<meta name="keywords" content="jane doe">` along with other keywords only found in the text of the website itself. As I type the name exactly in the search engine, it brings it up as top result in the google search engine.

Now let's say I have a subdirectory `http://www.janedoe.com/products/`, I type in jane doe products, it doesn't show in the search results at all regardless of the `<meta name="keywords" content="jane doe products">`.

However, if I copy and paste the exact URL `http://www.janedoe.com/products/`, it shows up in the search results. How can I make sure when I type in any of the specific keywords, it will show its parent domain as well as its subdirectory sites in the search engine?

I tried typing robots.txt in the root directory of website:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /products/
```

But doesn't seem to work. Or maybe it takes a while for the search engine to pick it up. I also wanted to block some web pages from the search engine in the root directory:

(For example I have: products.html, example.html, helloworld.html, index.html)
How do I block a specific webpage `helloworld.html` all within the same directory? I put this robots.txt file in the same directory:

```
User-agent: *
Dis-allow: /helloworld.html
```

and added `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`, but I don't know if I am on the right track or if it's effective.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight, you can get a good answer in the link provided in w3d's comment.

Comment: There's really no difference between subdirectories, the homepage, or any other page. Pages are assessed on their individual merits. And [Google (and most search engines) don't use the keywords meta tag in web ranking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)

Comment: Search engines match against pages not URLs although the URL/URI is a relatively minor factor in knowing what a page is about.

Comment: So how I can show the sub directory website in the search result because I have two separate websites I want to show up in the search engine (the parent domain that has an index.html which already shows and the sub directory domain which also has an index.html, which doesnt show.)